# How does use of make_unique prevent memory-leak, in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

```
fn(unique_ptr<A>{new A{}},unique_ptr<B>{new B{}});
```

is troublesome as `A` or `B` gets leaked if an exception is thrown there.

```
fn(make_unique<A>(),make_unique<B>());
```

on the other hand is considered exception-safe.

### Question:

Why? How does use of **make_unique** prevent *memory-leak*?
What does **make_unique** do that the *default* **unique_ptr** does not?

Kindly help me out, please.
Thank you.

Comment: make_unique has to do with exception safety. This link should give you all the info you're looking for: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/stdunique_ptr/. Next to "prevent memory leaks" std::unique_ptr models another important concept : ownership, unlinke raw_pointers you can see who's supposed to cleanup.

Comment: A quick search goes a long way. In addition to the duplicate question, also eg. https://www.py4u.net/discuss/67252 — make_unique ultimately creates a unique_ptr so it doesn’t “prevent a memory leak” any differently per se.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How does use of make_unique prevent memory-leak, in C++?

`std::make_unique` doesn't "prevent" memory-leak in the sense that it's still possible to write memory leaks in programs that use `std::make_unique`.

What does `std::make_unique` is make it easier to write programs that don't have memory leaks.

---

> A or B gets leaked if an exception is thrown there.
>
> Why?

Pre C++17:

Because if you allocate `A`, then call constructor of `B` before constructing the `std::unique_ptr` that was supposed to own `A`, and the constructor of `B` throws, then `A` will leak (or same happens with `A` and `B` reversed).

Since C++17:

There's no leak since the scenario described above cannot happen anymore in the shown example.

> What does make_unique do that the default unique_ptr does not?

`std::make_unique` allocates memory, and either successfully returns a valid `std::unique_ptr`, or throws an exception without leaking memory.

`std::unique_ptr(T*)` accepts a pointer that was allocated separately. If an exception is thrown before the constructor is called, then there will never have been a unique pointer owning the allocation.

---

It's possible to fix the (pre-C++17) bug without using `std::make_unique`:

```
auto a = std::unique_ptr<A>{new A{}};
auto b = std::unique_ptr<B>{new B{}};
fn(std::move(a), std::move(b));
```

But if you always use `std::make_unique`, then you won't accidentally make the mistake of writing leaky version. Furthermore, `std::make_unique` lets you avoid writing `new` which allows you to use the rule of thumb "write exactly one delete for each new". 0 new -> 0 delete.